# FlipView.SelectedIndex Mouse Mode vs Basic Touch Mode

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8

I have a databound `FlipView` on my page that works great. I have 2 Buttons on my page that I want to use to navigate the `FlipView` forward and back. The buttons work when I use `Mouse Mode` in the Simulator or actually use my mouse in Local Machine mode.

But when I use 'Basic touch mode' or use my app on an actual touch screen and tap the buttons, the FlipView navigates to next view but then flashes/flips back.

Here is my FlipView:

```
<FlipView x:Name="Flipper" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Views}">...</FlipView>
```

And my Button:

```
<Button x:Name="ForwardButton" IsEnabled="{Binding CanGoForward}" Style="{StaticResource ForwardButtonStyle}" Tapped="ForwardButton_OnTapped" />
```

And my event:

```
private void ForwardButton_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
            if (Flipper.SelectedIndex >= Flipper.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                Flipper.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Flipper.SelectedIndex++;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
 }
```

**Update:**

Adding `OnSelectionChanged` to the FlipView, I'm seeing it hit twice in `Basic touch mode`, but in `Mouse mode` only once, again `Mouse mode` works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so I implemented it like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    ViewModel ViewModel { get { return this.DataContext as ViewModel; } }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.MovePrevious();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.MoveNext();
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel() { SelectedThing = ThingList.First(); }

    List<int> m_ThingList = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).ToList();
    public List<int> ThingList { get { return m_ThingList; } set { SetProperty(ref m_ThingList, value); } }

    int m_SelectedThing = default(int);
    public int SelectedThing { get { return m_SelectedThing; } set { SetProperty(ref m_SelectedThing, value); } }

    internal void MovePrevious()
    {
        var _CurrentIndex = ThingList.IndexOf(this.SelectedThing);
        try { SelectedThing = ThingList[--_CurrentIndex]; }
        catch { SelectedThing = ThingList.First(); }
    }

    internal void MoveNext()
    {
        var _CurrentIndex = ThingList.IndexOf(this.SelectedThing);
        try { SelectedThing = ThingList[++_CurrentIndex]; }
        catch { SelectedThing = ThingList.Last(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            storage = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <Grid>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click_1">Previous</Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click_2">Next</Button>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <FlipView x:Name="MyFlip"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ThingList}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing,
                                        Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

Well, it worked correctly. Could you double check? Or provide more info? Otherwise, maybe an update to your implementation using mine as a guide can solve this for you. I hope so.

In all reality I would have used a DelegateCommand to handle the buttons. But I didn't want to overdo the example with too much boiler plate code. If you want to see what I would have done, you can look here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/most-people-are-doing-mvvm-all-wrong.html

Comment: Thanks, learned a lot about MVVM, I implemented your code and still getting the same behavior. It's odd how regular mouse mode works, if I click the buttons it works as expected, but in "basic touch mode" it flips back to the previous page.

Comment: I copied your code to a new solution and of course it worked flawlessly. So it's something I'm doing with the FlipView. Not sure what though.

Comment: Making progress. My buttons are within the ItemTemplate of the FlipView. I placed them in the AppBar and its working as expected. So I assume it has to do with multiple buttons being rendered. Still digging...

Comment: Yeah, it's not that you can't have them in the flipview. That works if you want it like that. But maybe the path of least resistance will help your app reach completion faster. ;)